# Is there a way to sort aws_ami by oldest instead of newest?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Right now I'm doing this:

```
data "aws_ami" "windows-image" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-*"]
  }
  owners = ["amazon"]
}
```

But I want to experiment with some outdated amis. There is no `oldest` param. If I could get aws_ami to return a list, I was thinking I could use `reverse()` on it, but it seems I need to do filtering otherwise I get this error:

```
Error: Your query returned more than one result. Please try a more specific search criteria, or set `most_recent` attribute to true.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw there is a separate resource for getting a *list* of ids.

```
data "aws_ami_ids" "windows-image" {
  sort_ascending = true // sort by oldest to newest
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-*"]
  }
  owners = ["amazon"]
}
output "test" {
  value = data.aws_ami_ids.windows-image.ids[0]
}
```